# MySQL backup and partial restored "snapshot" (time defined) with auto-increment id fields

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, restore, snapshot

Hope that some one can give me a hint here.

I have a mysql (Inno) database with multiple tables related between them by foreign keys.

My database has several Gigabytes of data now.

What I need to accomplish is: backup my actual database (ok mysqldump will take care of that for me), and I want to """clean""" the database and add only the data for the last month (for example), maintaining the integrity of all the rows that I want to restore. That is, imagine tables 1,2,3,4,5 (I have about 50):

Tables 1 and 2 have new rows every minute, table 3 is a "configuration" table that feeds (via foreign key in) tables 1 and 2, and tables 4 and 5 (these are not """configuration/base""" tables) are related by tables 1 and 2.

Ok, I understand that I have to restore all my "configuration/base" tables and contained rows in order to assure integrity of related "dependent" tables and to be possible to use those configured values.

But, how do I keep only the last month of every other table rows maintaining full integrity of the restored rows?

I thought in scripting something allied with the possible use of mysql binary logs.

All of my "id" fields are auto-increment and at any time I should be able to restore the complete database (in meltdown cases, or for "big picture" study/mining).

Thanks a million for any help given!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column to hold an entered date or a last modified date (or both) could help. You could use a trigger to set the date.

Comment: My problem isn't exactly the date by where I start the process, but the way to connect data from several tables using the foreign keys to keep other tables related rows in order to maintain full integrity of data. But thanks for your help